# How do I reference my data source to delete row from tableview using core data

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch, core-data

I want to delete a row from my tableview. I cannot find a solution that works from the other simialr questions here.

I know I need to use the following code, But I cant seem to figure out how to properly finish this line of code to make it work.

```
[dailyIncomeArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But what goes where is says "dailyIncomeArray"?

```
[what-goes-here removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

I have a getData method that populates my tableview. Next I want to be able to swipe to the left and hit that red delete button. Thanks in advance for your help!

Heres the rest of the method

```
    // Override to support editing the table view.
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete) {
        // Delete the row from the data source


        [dailyIncomeArray removeObjectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        [self.tableView reloadData];


        //[tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSMutableArray arrayWithObject:results] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
    }   
    else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert) {
        // Create a new instance of the appropriate class, insert it into the array, and add a new row to the table view
    }   
}
```

Here's the error I'm receiving. I don't understand what this means.

```
No visible @interface for 'NSArray' declares the selector 'removeObjectAtIndex:'
```

Comment: The error message is very clear: You cannot remove an object from an NSArray, because that is an *immutable* collection. - And how is this related to Core Data?

Comment: I don't know? Does it matter that I storing my data in a data model using Core Data and not sqlite? If it does then that would be how it is related. If it doesn't then I guess it doesn't relate at all?

Comment: Instead of using `NSArray` for `dailyIncomeArray`, use `NSMutableArray` which does have a `removeObjectAtIndex` selector. This will not, however, remove the object from core data, only from the array.

Comment: Have a look at `NSFetchedResultsController`, which is in many cases the best way (and easiest, once you get used to it) to display a table view with objects from Core Data. There are many tutorials about it in the web.

Comment: Hi bob, I did change the array to a mutable array. But now I have a warning in my getData method because I'm trying to set dailyIncomeArray = results; which is the NSArray my data is loaded into when I executeFetchRequest:request

Comment: Thank you Martin, I'm reading through the NSFetchedResultsController class reference, It is a lot to understand, I started teaching myself objective C about 2 months ago. I will try my best to understand how to utilize NSFetchedResultsController on my own but I definitely will be asking a lot more question about NSFetchedResultsController.

Comment: Check out the Ray Wenderlich tutorial on `NSFetchedResultsController` - highly recommended. http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller

Comment: To eliminate the warning (it's probably saying you are assigning an `NSArray` to an `NSMutableArray`), change `dailyIncomeArray = results;` to `dailyIncomeArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:results];`. Just remember deleting an object from the array does not delete it from core data. I agree with @MartinR that `NSFetchedResultsController` is likely what you want to use.